# How can I find out the size of each column in a Redshift table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

While trying out different compression settings in Redshift it would be very useful to know the size of each column. I know how to get the size of a table, but I want to know the size of each individual column in that table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query will give you the size (MB) of each column. What it does is that it counts the number of data blocks, where each block uses 1 MB, grouped by table and column.

```sql
SELECT
  TRIM(name) as table_name,
  TRIM(pg_attribute.attname) AS column_name,
  COUNT(1) AS size
FROM
  svv_diskusage JOIN pg_attribute ON
    svv_diskusage.col = pg_attribute.attnum-1 AND
    svv_diskusage.tbl = pg_attribute.attrelid
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

You can read more about the two tables involved in the query here:
[SVV_DISKUSAGE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_DISKUSAGE.html) & 
[pg_attribute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html).

Answer (score 3):

A more accurate size of the table would include the hidden system columns `deletexid`, `insertxid`, `oid` (ROW ID), as well. One of my tables was using 752 blocks without including the hidden columns. When i added the hidden columns, it went upto 1063 blocks.

```
SELECT col, attname, COUNT(*) AS "mbs"
FROM stv_blocklist bl
JOIN stv_tbl_perm perm
  ON bl.tbl = perm.id AND bl.slice = perm.slice    
LEFT JOIN pg_attribute attr ON
  attr.attrelid = bl.tbl
  AND attr.attnum-1 = bl.col  
WHERE perm.name = '<TABLE-NAME>'  
GROUP BY col, attname
ORDER BY col;
```

Comment: Useful, but the premise of the original question is testing the effect of different encodings on user-columns, not the full table size, so hidden columns not that important. For Redshift, it might be better to query the total table info from `SVV_TABLE_INFO`

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a view that contains both the table size and the column size - I believe one would usually want to optimize the largest columns of the largest tables:

```
    with db_stats as (SELECT database, schema, "table", size, tbl_rows, table_id
                  FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO
                  order by size desc),
table_stats as (
SELECT
    tbl,
  TRIM(name) as table_name,
  TRIM(pg_attribute.attname) AS column_name,
  COUNT(1) AS size
FROM
  svv_diskusage JOIN pg_attribute ON
    svv_diskusage.col = pg_attribute.attnum-1 AND
    svv_diskusage.tbl = pg_attribute.attrelid
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 )

select database, schema, "table", tbl_rows, column_name, db_stats.size as table_size, table_stats.size as column_size
from db_stats left join table_stats on db_stats.table_id = table_stats.tbl
order by db_stats.size desc, table_stats.size desc;
```